# Differential compression software

Tags: file-compression

Suppose these:

1. Everyone in the world (or at least my audiences) has downloaded the file *ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso* with md5sum of *0d9fe8e1ea408a5895cbbe3431989295* which is approximately *1.5GB* in size
2. I distribute virtual machine appliances based on that version of Ubuntu in *Open Virtualization Format* (OVF).
3. My Virtual Appliance consists of many packages of the Ubuntu ISO image in installed (extracted) format and a few megabytes of configurations and applications I have added.  When I export it to OVF, it gives an *8GB* file

Now this is the question: Is there a software I can use that performs remote-differential-compression (or performs BLOB-Seeded-Compression in my own terms)?

**NOTE**: This compression software is supposed to know that me and my audiences share  a common large iso image containing compressed versions of most content that I publish (their extracted versions) in OVF. The software should output a file in a few megabytes that I can deliver to customers. When they want to extract the content it asks for a file with *0d9fe8e1ea408a5895cbbe3431989295* checksum and creates the 8GB ovf file.

Comment: Does [zsync](http://zsync.moria.org.uk/) do what you want?

Comment: Well, it appears conceptually close, I should give it a try. [to @steve-barnes:]: I seek some generic approach like this one, In fact VM deployment is just one rationale or use-case that I described.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than differential compression I would suggest taking a look at tools such as [Vagrant Up](https://www.vagrantup.com/) where you can distribute a recipe, components and settings as plain text files and links to the components.

I think that you will find this a lot more efficient as the large downloads get reused and you can target various VMs, etc.